# Good implementation

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, go

I'm trying to do the following `MySQL` query

With this query it is possible to obtain the classification of the car in a race, and the drivers of these cars

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM results 
INNER JOIN cars ON results.idCar = cars.Id
INNER JOIN drivers ON cars.id = drivers.idCar
WHERE idSesson = 7 
ORDER BY classification
ASC
```

This query returns 2 Models: Result, Session. And returns a list of drivers for each car

The problem is that it returns the result of each pilot, that is, the same result can appear 3 times only the pilot is different, and I want to add the pilots within a `JSONArray`

Used this query I used this implementation

```
    result := structs.Result{}
    lastResult := structs.Result{}
    results := []structs.Result{}
    driver := structs.Driver{}
    drivers := []structs.Driver{}
    for rows.Next() {
        var sesson structs.Sesson
        var car structs.Car

        err = rows.Scan(&result.Id, &sesson.Id, &car.Id, &result.Type, &result.Classification, &result.Category, &car.Id, &car.IdTeam, 
            &car.Name, &car.Number, &car.Model, &car.Manufacturer, &car.TyerBrand, &car.CarImage, &driver.Id, &driver.IdCar,
            &driver.Name, &driver.Age, &driver.DateOfBrith, &driver.Country, &driver.FlagCountry, &driver.Facebook, &driver.Twitter, &driver.Website, &driver.Picture)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error in scan")
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        result.Sesson = sesson
        result.Car = car
        drivers = append(drivers, driver) // i stor the drivers in one array

        // check if end the duplicated, info
        if (lastResult.Id != 0 && lastResult.Id != result.Id) {
            results = append(results, lastResult)
        }
        
        // store the last result
        lastResult = result
    }

    // add last result
    results = append(results, lastResult)

    // save the drivers in JSONArray in each jsonObject
    for i := 0; i < len(results); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(drivers); j++ {
            if (results[i].Car.Id == drivers[j].IdCarro) {
                results[i].Drivers = append(results[i].Drivers, drivers[j])
            }
        }
    }

    // transform data in json
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(results)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error in marsahl")
    }

    db.Close()

    return jsonData
```

Is this a good implementation? For this problem ??

I can get the result in **302ms**

```
[
    {
        "id": 44,
        "sesson": {
            "id": 33,
            "name": "",
            "date": "",
            "startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "endTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "raceId": 0
        },
        "car": {
            "id": 10,
            "idTeam": 6,
            "name": "AF CORSE",
            "number": 54,
            "model": "Ferrari 488 GTE",
            "manufactor": "Ferrari",
            "tyerBrand": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ecm-prod/assets/Tyre/wec-2019-logo-tyres-app_435d35.png",
            "carImage": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ecm-prod/media/cache/entry_car_md/assets/1/engage/45325/lmgte_743f0c.png"
        },
        "type": 7,
        "drivers": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "idCar": 10,
                "name": "Thomas Flohr",
                "age": 60,
                "dateOfBrith": "1960-03-01",
                "country": "Switzerland",
                "countryFlag": "urlCountryFlag",
                "facebook": "facebook.com",
                "twitter": "twitter.com",
                "website": "website.com",
                "foto": "urlFoto"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "idTeam": 10,
                "name": "Francesco Castellacci",
                "age": 33,
                "dateOfBrith": "1987-04-03",
                "country": "Italy",
                "countryFlag": "urlCountryFlag",
                "facebook": "facebook.com",
                "twitter": "twwitter.com",
                "website": "website.com",
                "foto": "pictureUrl"
            }
        ],
        "classification": 13,
        "category": 3
    }
 ]
```

This is the result in `JSON`.

Is it a good solution to solve this problem??

Comment: I think a map whose key is [session, car] and whose value is a list of drivers would be of help here

Comment: Yes use map will significantly reduce the complexity from n^2 to n

Comment: How much time your query takes?  If you share your DB structure we might be able to see if query is not optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few Things you can do

1. Fix the scope of result variable, Move it inside the loop it is not used anywhere else
2. Instead of creating session and car variables scan directly into result variable
3. Use a map to remove nested for loop will save your time getting linear complexity